# Player character turns about halfway and then stops

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just got Minecraft, and I was really excited to start playing it, but when I joined a world, I noticed that I turned halfway or so and then stopped. I think that it is because an invisible cursor is hitting the edges of the screen, but I don't know. I can't play successfully because of this.

Edit: I am using Linux to run Minecraft.

Comment: Hello, can your question be more specific? I do not understand

Comment: i think he means he can only turn half way around

Comment: Have you clicked into the game window? Try pressing `Esc` to open the game menu, then click on an empty space there and `Esc` again to return to the game. Does it then behave normally?

Answer (score 3):

Turning/Looking in Minecraft is tied to your mouse movement.

Basically, when you move your mouse, your avatar will look around. When you stop moving your mouse; so will your avatar.

Normally, while in game (and not interacting with any UI) your "cursor" will be pinned to the center of the screen, to allow for unlimited movement. The only reason that this isn't the case, is if your game is not the primary focus. This could be for many reasons, such as system notifications, backgrounds apps, or even a bug.

Every time this happens, you should be able to ensure that Minecraft is the main window that has focus, by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to change which application is your main window.

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't work. Alt+Tab isn't working while I am in Minecraft.

Comment: That's concerning, Alt+Tab should always work (except on my system, but that's a long story and I know why). What operating system are you using? Did you do anything special, like changing hotkeys or keyboard layout, are some system modificating programs installed?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your cursor doesn't snap to the middle of the screen every tick, as it should.
If the problem persists, you could use a program to do this for you. If you have a C++ compiler, you can do it yourself like this (*yes, I know this isn't Stack Overflow*):

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
while(1)
{

   if(GetKeyState(0x5A)==1)
   SetCursorPos(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
   Sleep(1);
}
}
```

Feel free to copy the code above, compile it and then keep it open in the background while playing the game. It may be a bit uncomfortable, but it's better than not being able to play altogether. **Press Z to toggle the program off for navigating through your inventory, chests, menus and such.**
Edit: also try to downgrade to an older version, and see if it's fixed.

Comment: I tried running it but it gave me this error:
`mc.cpp:1:1: error: ‘include’ does not name a type
 include <windows.h>
 ^~~~~~~`

Comment: I've forgot the #, apparently. Add a # before include.

Comment: i am on linux, so this isn working? can you make one for linux?

Comment: @Stevehead25 I don't know how to do it for Linux, but I'll search for how to do it.

Comment: thank you so much @John! i might finally be able to play!

Comment: @Stevehead25 It wouldn't be an excellent, so also consider playing on an older version.

Comment: @Stevehead25 Unfortunately, it seems a bit more complicated in Linux: you need the header xlib.h, and the program is generally much messier. I'll still try to do it, but it'll take a while.